# Value of type 'String' has no member indices

Tags: swift, xcode, string, swift3

I am trying to migrate my Swift 2.2 code to Swift 3(beta) and I am getting the following error in the below code after migrating to Swift 3.0 ,**"Value of type 'String' has no member indices"**

Would require help on the following were `routePathComponent` is a String.

**After Migrating**

```
if routePathComponent.hasPrefix(":") {
   let variableKey = routePathComponent.substring(with: routePathComponent.indices.suffix(from: routePathComponent.characters.index(routePathComponent.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)))
}
```

**Before Migrating**

```
if routePathComponent.hasPrefix(":") {
                            let variableKey = routePathComponent.substringWithRange(routePathComponent.startIndex.advancedBy(1)..<routePathComponent.endIndex)
                            let variableValue = component.URLDecodedString()
                            if variableKey.characters.count > 0 && variableValue.characters.count > 0 {
                                variables[variableKey] = variableValue
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to omit the first character if it's a colon, that's the Swift 3 way

```
if routePathComponent.hasPrefix(":") {
  let variableKey = routePathComponent.substring(from: routePathComponent.index(after :routePathComponent.startIndex))
}
```

The equivalent of your other example in the comment is

```
if let endingQuoteRange = clazz.range(of:"\"") {
   clazz.removeSubrange(endingQuoteRange.upperBound..<clazz.endIndex)
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution .let me try your solution.I am trying to upgrade a code written 2 years back and i struggling to find the purpose of the above piece of code asked in the question

Comment: Can you post the original Swift 2.2 code. The code in the question seems to be migrated already.

Comment: Yes it does cut off the first character, my code is the Swift 3 equivalent

Comment: It certainly will.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue in the following code. if let endingQuoteRange = clazz.range(of: "\"") {
                
                clazz.removeSubrange((clazz.indices.suffix(from: endingQuoteRange.startIndex)))    
                return getClassNameFromFullClassName(clazz)
            } any idea

Comment: sorry ...if let endingQuoteRange = clazz.rangeOfString("\"") {
                clazz.removeRange(Range<String.Index>(start: endingQuoteRange.startIndex,
                    end: clazz.endIndex))
                return getClassNameFromFullClassName(clazz)
            }

Comment: Thanks ..can you explain me what does .upperbound and .endIndex does..thanks for your patience

Comment: `rangeOf` returns the range of the quote in the string (`lowerBound..<upperBound`). `lowerBound` is the character itself, `upperBound` is the first character after the quote. `removeSubrange` removes everything after the quote `endingQuoteRange.upperBound` until the end of the string `clazz.endIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dropFirst()` if you want just drop first character from String.

```
if routePathComponent.hasPrefix(":") {
    let variableKey = String(routePathComponent.characters.dropFirst())
}
```

Comment: Hi i have pasted the swift 2.2 code before migrating .I am still stuggling to find the purpose of the above code.since its 2 years old written by a developer who is not available anymore

Comment: @user578386 Have you try using `String(routePathComponent.characters.dropFirst())` like my answer?

Comment: works fine..I have similar query if let endingQuoteRange = clazz.range(of: "\"") {
                
                clazz.removeSubrange((clazz.indices.suffix(from: endingQuoteRange.startIndex)))
                
                return getClassNameFromFullClassName(clazz)
            
            }

Comment: @user578386 Sorry for late but Vadian have already given you want you want.

Answer (score 0):

`indices` is property of `Collection` types. `String` is not `Collection` since v.2.3.

Use `.characters` property, which returns `Collection` of characters of the `String`.

Comment: I tried using .characters and i get the following error " No 'index' canditate produce the expected contextual result type 'Int'".Can you check the above code from your end and were i could have possibly gone wrong.I would be much grateful

Comment: Well, maybe you should look for different solution for your problem. Do you need just drop initial ":"? Why not just use `String(string.characters.dropFirst())` or something like that?

Comment: The above is a 2 year old code written by a different developer who is available no more and I am having trouble understanding the purpose of the above piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var routePathComponent = ":Hello playground"


if routePathComponent.hasPrefix(":") {
    let variableKey = routePathComponent.substringFromIndex(routePathComponent.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
    //print(variableKey)
}
```

This should do the trick

Comment: I tried using .characters and i gott the following error " No 'index' canditate produce the expected contextual result type 'Int'".

Comment: `advancedBy` is not available in Swift 3